# Access $scope from within event bound inside the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to access the $scope of a directive inside an element event. However, it is not happening.

When the $element blurs, the div, dyamically created, should have a class called "isok" because of the ng-class

```
  app.directive('advformInput', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                var div = angular.element('<div class="advform-input" ng-class="{isok:isok}">' +
                    '<div class="helper">' + $attrs.advformInput + '</div></div>');
                var e = $compile(div)($scope);
                var par = $element.parent();

                $scope.isok = 0;
                par.append(e);

                $element.on('blur', function($event){
                    var par = $(this).parents('.advform-input:first');

                    par.removeClass('isfocused');

                    if ($($event.target).val())
                        par.addClass('hasval')
                    else
                        par.removeClass('hasval')

                    $scope.isok = 1;
                })
                $element.on('focus', function($event){
                    div.addClass('isfocused')
                });

                e.append($element);
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `$scope.$digest()` after changing the value of `isok`.

The short explanation is that angular is ignorant of when a jQuery event fires and you've got to tell it that something has changed.